# Node Js - SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below code in service.js file.

```
exports.getSeminarDetailsById = async function (seminarId) {
try {
    let SeminarList = [];
    var seminarData = await SeminarRepository.getSeminarDetailsById(seminarId);
    if (seminarData && seminarData.length > 0) {
        let userIdList = [...new Set(seminarData.map(x => x.user_id))];
        if (userIdList && userIdList.length > 0) {
            let userDetails = await EmployeeRepository.getEmployeeDetailsByUserIds(userIdList);
            if (userDetails && userDetails.length > 0) {
                seminarData.forEach(element => {
                    let seminarDetail;
                    let userName = userDetails.filter(x => x.user_id == element.user_id).map(x => x.userfullname)[0];
                    let categoryName;
                    if (element.category_id == 1)
                        categoryName = AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.TECHNICAL;
                    else
                        categoryName = AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.NONTECHNICAL;

                    seminarDetail = new SeminarTrackerDetails(element, userName, categoryName);
                    await mapAttachmentWithSeminar(seminarId, seminarDetail);
                    console.log("second", seminarDetail);
                    SeminarList.push(seminarDetail);
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return SeminarList;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
}
}
```

Here error comes on `await mapAttachmentWithSeminar(seminarId, seminarDetail);` and it is defined in the same file as below.

```
async function mapAttachmentWithSeminar(seminarId, seminarDetail) {
var seminarAttachmentDetails = await SeminarRepository.getSeminarAttachmentDetailsById(seminarId);
  if (seminarAttachmentDetails && seminarAttachmentDetails.length > 0) {
    let AttachmentDetails = [];
    seminarAttachmentDetails.forEach(element => {
        let attachmentDetails = new SeminarAttachmentDetails(element);
        AttachmentDetails.push(attachmentDetails);
    });
    seminarDetail.SeminarAttachmentDetails = AttachmentDetails;
  }
  else {
    seminarDetail.SeminarAttachmentDetails = null;
    console.log("first", seminarDetail);
  }
}
```

If I remove the await function, then `console.log("second", seminarDetail);` will be executed first before executing the function `mapAttachmentWithSeminar()`. So that the value of `SeminarAttachmentDetails` returning from that function will be missed as shown below:

[image]

This was the expected output.

[image]

Comment: The error is obvious. Reword this question so it's more condensed with a "I have X but need to output Y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.forEach` you could go with a classic `for` loop

```
for(let i = 0; i < seminarData.length; i++){
    let element = seminarData[i];
    let seminarDetail;
    let userName = userDetails.filter(x => x.user_id == element.user_id).map(x => x.userfullname)[0];
    let categoryName;
    if (element.category_id == 1)
        categoryName = AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.TECHNICAL;
    else
        categoryName = AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.NONTECHNICAL;

    seminarDetail = new SeminarTrackerDetails(element, userName, categoryName);
    await mapAttachmentWithSeminar(seminarId, seminarDetail);
    console.log("second", seminarDetail);
    SeminarList.push(seminarDetail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

every nested function should be declared as `async` as well as parent's.
in your case this declaration is missed in one of nesting level, pay attention on this part of code

```js
seminarData.forEach(async element => {
//                  ^^^^ async missed here
 let seminarDetail;
 let userName = userDetails.filter(x => x.user_id == element.user_id).map(x => x.userfullname)[0];
 let categoryName;
 if (element.category_id == 1)
  categoryName = AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.TECHNICAL;
 else
  categoryName = AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.NONTECHNICAL;
 seminarDetail = new SeminarTrackerDetails(element, userName, categoryName);
 await mapAttachmentWithSeminar(seminarId, seminarDetail); 
 console.log("second", seminarDetail); 
 SeminarList.push(seminarDetail);
});
```

Comment: Above code doesn't return any error rather it returns empty list

Comment: that code doesn't change logic of your application, it just fixes error you faced with.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Don't downvote it because your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First you are using wrong async await. You are awaiting inside the scope of a function which is not async.
Here:

```
 seminarData.forEach(element => {
                let seminarDetail;
                let userName = userDetails.filter(x => x.user_id == element.user_id).map(x => x.userfullname)[0];
                let categoryName;
                if (element.category_id == 1)
                    categoryName = AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.TECHNICAL;
                else
                    categoryName = AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.NONTECHNICAL;

                seminarDetail = new SeminarTrackerDetails(element, userName, categoryName);
                await mapAttachmentWithSeminar(seminarId, seminarDetail);
                console.log("second", seminarDetail);
                SeminarList.push(seminarDetail);
            });
```

You should have this

```
 // here you have the SeminarList but promisified
 // with the form Promise<SeminarListItem>[]
 // to get the values out of the promises you have to await this array     
    const promisifiedSeminarList = seminarData.map((element)=>{
         let userName = userDetails.filter(x => x.user_id == element.user_id).map(
            x => x.userfullname)[0]
         );

        const categoryName = elemenet.category_id == 1
          ? AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.TECHNICAL
          : AppConstants.seminarCategoryName.NONTTECHNICAL;

       const seminarDetail = new SeminarTrackerDetails(element, userName, categoryName);
       return mapAttachmentWithSeminar(seminarId, seminarDetail);
    });
  // now
   const seminarList = await Promise.all(promisifiedSeminarList);
```

For that to work you need that the function mapAttachmentWithSemniar returns a value which is not happening